# "Cannot POST /graphql" - "Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, graphql, apollo

**Hola, tengo un problema al registrar un usuario. Si lo registro desde el Sandbox de Apollo no tengo ningun problema, pero al implementar la funcion al componente en React me arroja este error desde la consola de Chrome:**

```
Error: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
at new ApolloError (index.ts:56)
at Object.error (QueryManager.ts:307)
at notifySubscription (module.js:137)
at onNotify (module.js:176)
at SubscriptionObserver.error (module.js:229)
at Object.error (asyncMap.ts:48)
at notifySubscription (module.js:137)
at onNotify (module.js:176)
at SubscriptionObserver.error (module.js:229)
at iteration.ts:13
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at iterateObserversSafely (iteration.ts:13)
at Object.error (Concast.ts:185)
at notifySubscription (module.js:137)
at onNotify (module.js:176)
at SubscriptionObserver.error (module.js:229)
at createHttpLink.ts:201
```

**La funcion de registro se ejecuta desde aca en React**

```
const formik = useFormik({
initialValues: initialValues(),
//Validaciones del formulario
validationSchema: Yup.object({
  name: Yup.string().required("Tu nombre es obligatorio"),
  username: Yup.string()
    .matches(
      /^[a-zA-Z0-9-]*$/,
      "El nombre del usuario no puede tener espacio o caracteres especiales"
    )
    .required("Tu nombre de usuario es obligatorio"),
  email: Yup.string()
    .email("El email no es valido")
    .required("El email es obligatorio"),
  password: Yup.string()
    .required("Las contraseñas son obligatorias")
    .oneOf(
      [Yup.ref("repeatPassword")],
      "Las contraseñas deben ser iguales"
    ),
  repeatPassword: Yup.string()
    .required("Las contraseñas son obligatorias")
    .oneOf([Yup.ref("password")], "Las contraseñas deben ser iguales"),
}),
//Funcion a ejecutar cuando se ejecute "onSubmit" en el formulario
//formValues: contiene los valores ingresados en el formulario
onSubmit: async (formData) => {
  try {
    const newUser = formData;
    delete newUser.repeatPassword;

    const result = await register({
      variables: {
        input: newUser,
      },
    });

    console.log(result);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
},
```

});

**Como dije con el Sandbox de Apollo puedo registrar usuarios sin problemas, el error aparece al intentarlo desde el cliente React.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontre el error, en el archivo con la configuracion para crear la conexion entre el cliente y el servidor, al crear el httpLink estaba mal tipeada la palabra "uri", yo estaba colocando "url" :´)

```
import { ApolloClient, createHttpLink, InMemoryCache } from 
"@apollo/client";

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
   uri: "http://localhost:4000/graphql",
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
   connectToDevTools: true,
   cache: new InMemoryCache(),
   link: httpLink,
});

export default client;
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.